# Rails app not working after upgrading from 6.1.3.1 to 6.1.4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running a Rails 6.1.3.1 application, after upgrading to 6.1.4.1 I'm no longer able to start the server.

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.4.1 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    65: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    64: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    63: from /Users/sig/Code/reaction6/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    62: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    61: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    60: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    59: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    58: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    57: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    56: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    55: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    54: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    53: from /Users/sig/Code/reaction6/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    52: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    51: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    50: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    49: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    48: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    47: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    46: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    45: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    44: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    43: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    42: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    41: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
    40: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `tap'
    39: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:144:in `block in perform'
    38: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
    37: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
    36: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    35: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    34: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    33: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    32: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    31: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    30: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    29: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    28: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require_relative'
    27: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    26: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    25: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    24: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    23: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    22: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    21: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    20: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    19: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    18: from /Users/sig/Code/reaction6/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    17: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
    16: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    15: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    14: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    13: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    12: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    11: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    10: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
     9: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
     8: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
     7: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
     6: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
     5: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
     4: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
     3: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:59:in `block in <module:Bootstrap>'
     2: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/cache.rb:64:in `lookup_store'
     1: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/cache.rb:64:in `new'
/Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb:23:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
```

I tried to upgrade all the gems and packages as well but without success.

My `package.json` looks like

```
{
  "name": "reaction",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.1.4",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.1.4",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.1.4",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^5.4.3",
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.9",
    "highcharts": "^9.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "stimulus": "^2.0.0",
    "stimulus-flatpickr": "^1.4.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3"
  }
}
```

So, I don't think the issue is related to `webpack-dev-server` version 4+ (found some answers about that while seeking for a solution).

How can I proceed to find the real issue here?

Comment: Looking at the 6.1.4 changelog (https://github.com/rails/rails/releases/tag/v6.1.4), I see "Require a path for `config.cache_store = :file_store`." So maybe check for that config somewhere in the app and see if it's missing.

Comment: @ellitt thanks, your comment pointed me in the right direction. I had a `config.cache_store = :file_store` without path in my development config.